# WPF how does scrollviewer respond to requests for sizes greater than the available size?

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

So as I understand it, during measure scrollviewer will first be passed the available size of its parent, e.g. width of 10, height of 10

Despite having a 10x10 region available, it will then pass its children (infinity, infinity) as the available size when it measures its children.

I am curious about what happens next. the children will take that size, and make a requested size to the scrollviewer. If the requested size of the child is larger than the available size to scrollviewer, does the scrollviewer take on the size of the child or the size available to scrollviewer?

And afterward does the scrollviewer's width and height get modified or only the scrollviewer's actual width and actual height?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout process is a two step process. First objects receive a Measure request, typically the Size passed to them is large as this request should return the size the control requires. The scroll viewer will calculate the sizes it totally requires and return it. It actually asks it's children what their total size requirements will be.

Next step will be Arrange step where each control receives the available size. The scroll viewer will now receive the real size to which it need to constrain itself and its children.

Widht and Height are never modified by the layout process, instead ActualWidth and ActualHeight are populated with the actual size.

Comment: I guess I'm still a little confused, cause if the scrollviewer gets the actual available size during arrange, then what does the child receive in arrange? I feel like black magic goes on to make only a portion of the child be shown in the scrollviewer and the rest to be capable of being scrolled to.

does the child render itself entirely in infinite space? anyway, your answer helped so I will go test out what is happening in arrange. I assume that the actualwidth and actualheight of the child are modified after arrange